# Error when using np.boot from the nptest package - missing values and NaN not allowed

Tags: r, statistics

Listed below is my code and Error in R

CODE

```
library(nptest)

set.seed(1000)

bootstrap_primary_premium=np.boot(Primary,statistic=mean, R=500)

print(bootstrap_primary_premium)
```

ERROR

```
Error in quantile.default(bootdist[, j], probs = probs) :

  missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Non parametric bootstrapping

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(Primary)` as part of your question in order to reproduce the problem. Also, as per the error message, have you tried with `np.boot(Primary,statistic=mean, R=500, na.rm = TRUE)`?

Comment: Yes I have tried with na.rm=TRUE. It didn't help

Comment: We can't help you until you provide the output of `dput(Primary)`

Comment: dput(Primary)
structure(list(dataset2 = c(28.13, 260.91, 36.7, 252.47, 6.21, 
72.33, 42.24, 128.86, 198.03, 62.87, 103.8, 12.12, 5.88, 27607.09, 
90.31, 1530.13, 106.31, 14.17, 273, 358.88, 63.87, 180.06, 195.32, 
993.3, 1055.01, 554.48, 49.4, 432.47, 31.6, 315.35, 307.4, 195.99, 
702.67

Comment: Please edit your question with that output. The comment section doesn't accommodate for that.